# Exception on StoreContext.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync

Tags: c#, .net, exception, uwp, app-update

I am new in **.Net** development. In a UWP app i need to check for **package update** in Store. I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates) tutorial. For below code i am getting Exception.

```
 StoreContext context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
 // Get the updates that are available.
 IReadOnlyList<StorePackageUpdate> updates =
 await context.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();
```

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll An exception of type
> 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code The system
> cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

I can't find any hint why i am getting this exception. Please help my about this exception and how can i resolve this.

Comment: Is your app already on the Microsoft Store? This method requires you to upload at least one package of the app in the store

Comment: I think its on beta testing . any suggestion @RoyLi-MSFT

Comment: So it is already in the Store, right? Have you tried other APIs like in-app-purchase to see if other APIs work correctly?

Comment: I didn't tried other API yet

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT i have tried `context.GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync()` for in app purchase and its returns without any exception

Comment: I found a similar issue on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Dev-Performance/issues/22). It sounds like you might need to submit App Assure request here: https://aka.ms/appassurerequest So the store team could check if they could help you fix this.